# Stop the text getting separated into two columns

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, writing

I am writing a journal paper using IEEE style. In that, each page is divided into two columns. The content is written in the first column and once the space is over the content goes to the second one. But I encountered an issue in the final page of the paper.

In that when I write my content in the first column, after the first row is filled, the next word I write goes to the second column. Following screen shot will clear the things for you.

I need the final portion of my content in the final page to be filled as a single column. How can I avoid the content getting separated into two?

---

[image: Word two columns]

Answer (score 1):

Insert a continuous section break before the final piece of text and set the number of columns in the new section to 1.